# Python: Como atribuir valores em n dimensoes arbitrárias?

Tags: python, numpy, índices

Tenho dois arrays de n dimensoes (i.e. len(A.shape)==len(B.shape)), sendo que um 'cabe' no outro (seja o primeiro A, o segundo B, para toda dimensao i de A e B, A.shape[i]>=B.shape[i])
Quero atribuir os valores de B para os índices iniciais de A.

Para n fixo, digamos, 3, é trivial:

```
s=B.shape
A[:s[0],:s[1],:s[2]]=B
```

Porém, para n arbitrário (dependente da dimensao dos arrays, passado pelo usuário), como eu posso fazer?
Nao existe a notacao

```
s=B.shape
A[:s[0],:s[1],:s[2],...,:s[n]]=B
```

Algum insight?

Comment: Isso é o que, é o pacote Pandas, NumPy?

Comment: numpy.
Mas posso mudar se houver solucao em algum outro pacote.

Comment: Não precisa mudar só para identificar qual a documentação a ler ao procurar a solução.

Answer (score 1):

Vamos lá -

NumPy faz um uso interessante da sintaxe de `objeto[ ...]` do Python, e consegue usar a mesma para endereçar índices multidimensionais e até faixas de índices em cada dimensão - além de outros usos (como máscara de elementos, se o objeto dentro do índice for um array booleano, por exemplo).

O que permite tudo isso é o mecanismo de sobrecarga de operadores do Python - basicamente o que está dentro dos colchetes numa expressão do tipo `objeto[...]` é passado para o método `__getitem__` do mesmo objeto, se for um acesso pra leitura, e para o método `__setitem__` se for um acesso de atribuição (`objeto[...] = ...`).

E aí tem basicamente duas coisas a mais definidas na sintaxe da línguagem: elementos dentro do colchete separados por `,` são passados como uma tupla para o `__getitem__/__setitem__`,e "fatias" definidas com o uso de `:` são passados como um objeto do tipo `slice`. Um acesso do tipo `objeto[0:5, 2:7]` é passado como uma tupla de 2 posições, cada uma contendo um objeto do tipo `slice`. Um `slice` por sua vez é um objetinho bem simples - que basicamente tem três atributos `start`, `stop` e `step`.

Tudo isso para dizer que: você pode construir essa tupla de slices programaticamente, como se cria uma tupla qualquer, e chamar explicitamente o método `__setitem__`.

Então, dá pra fazer assim -

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np                                                                                                                          

In [2]: a np.zeros((5,5,5))                                                                                                                         
  File "<ipython-input-2-9dd98a1448d1>", line 1
    a np.zeros((5,5,5))
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


In [3]: a =np.zeros((5,5,5))                                                                                                                        

In [4]: b = np.zeros((3, 3, 3))                                                                                                                     

In [5]: b += 5                                                                                                                                      

In [6]: b                                                                                                                                           
Out[6]: 
array([[[5., 5., 5.],
        [5., 5., 5.],
        [5., 5., 5.]],

       [[5., 5., 5.],
        [5., 5., 5.],
        [5., 5., 5.]],

       [[5., 5., 5.],
        [5., 5., 5.],
        [5., 5., 5.]]])

In [7]: a                                                                                                                                           
Out[7]: 
array([[[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],
...
       [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]])


In [10]: indices = tuple(slice(0, b.shape[i]) for i in range(len(b.shape)))                                                                        

In [11]: a.__setitem__(indices, b)                                                                                                                  

In [12]: a                                                                                                                                          
Out[12]: 
array([[[5., 5., 5., 0., 0.],
        [5., 5., 5., 0., 0.],
        [5., 5., 5., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[5., 5., 5., 0., 0.],
        [5., 5., 5., 0., 0.],
        [5., 5., 5., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[5., 5., 5., 0., 0.],
        [5., 5., 5., 0., 0.],
        [5., 5., 5., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]])
```

A expressão `indices = tuple(slice(0, b.shape[i]) for i in range(len(b.shape)))`  faz o que eu descrevi acima: para cada dimensão no shape de b (no caso 3x3x3 e 5x5x5 para o a: dimensão e comprimento do shape são 3), cria um objeto "slice" dizendo o tamanho daquela dimensão que queremos ter como "alvo" em "a" - slice(0, 3) dentro da tupla é o mesmo que `[0:3, ...]` dentro do colchete.

Suponho que você entenda o `for` inline aí nessa expressão - o conjunto todo `slice(0, b.shape[i]) for i in range(len(b.shape))` é uma "generator expression", que quando passada como parâmetro para o construtor da classe `tuple` cria uma tupla com cada valor gerado.

E na sequência, o método `a.__setitem__` é chamado, como descrivi acima: com a tupla de slices explícita se comportando exatamente como a expressão `[0:3, 0:3, 0:3]` - e o segundo parâmetro o "valor" que vamos atribuir para as slices selecionadas. (Como as slices reproduzem o shape de b, ele 'encaixa' certinho).

---

Agora, supondo-se que esse mecanismo do  `__setitem__` não existisse, ou fosse muito mais complicado - um outro caminho seria gerar programaticamente a `"a[0:3, 0:3, [0:3] = b"` como uma string, e efetuar uma chamada a `exec`- que compila e executa uma string contendo código Python.  O uso de `eval` e `exec` no entanto não é recomendado se não há necessidade: é fácil introduzir vulnerabilidades de segurança em código usando o mesmo, e a performance deles também é muito ruim (por que envolve compilar o código Python na string).